# Core data slow processing updates on a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am having a major problem with my application speed in processing updates on a background thread. Instruments shows that almost all of this time is spend inside `performBlockAndWait` where I am fetching out the objects which need updating.

My updates may come in by the hundreds depending on the amount of time offline and the approach I am currently using is to process them individually; ie fetch request to pull out the object, update, then save.

It sounds slow and it is. The problem I have is that I don't want to load everything into memory at once, so need to fetch them individually as we go, also I save as I go to ensure that if there is an issue with a single update it won't mess up the rest.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit similar slow performance when upserting a large collection of objects. In my case I'm willing to keep the full change set in memory and perform a single save so the large volume of fetch requests dominated my processing time.

I got a significant performance improvement from maintaining an in memory cache mapping my resources' primary keys to `NSManagedObjectID`s. That allowed me to use [`existingObjectWithId:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/existingObjectWithID:error:) rather than a fetch request for an individual object.

I suspect I might do even better by collecting the primary keys for all resources of a given entity description, issuing a single fetch request for all of them at once (batching those results as necessary), and then processing the changes to each resource.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from using `NSBatchUpdateRequest` assuming you're targeting iOS 8+ only.

[These guys have a great example of it](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/) but the TLDR is basically:

*Example: Say we want to update all unread instances of MyObject to be marked as read:*

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *req = [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyObject"];
req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"read == %@", @(NO)];
req.propertiesToUpdate = @{
    @"read" : @(YES)
};
req.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType;
NSBatchUpdateResult *res = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[context executeRequest:req error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@ objects updated", res.result);
```

Note the above example is taken from the aforementioned blog, I didn't write the snippet.

Comment: The updates aren't related in anyway though so I don't see how I could batch them.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't glean from the original question that they were unrelated updates. You may be out of luck then, unless you can maybe batch groups of them. E.g., suppose you have updates of types A, B and C, you could queue them up individually and then periodically do a batch update of all A's, a batch update of all B's, etc.